# Prevent Visual Studio from connecting to Team Foundation Server on startup

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, registry

Visual Studio automatically tries to connect to Team Foundation Server on startup but sometimes when you frequently change TFS servers it takes a long time for Visual Studio to timeout on its attempt to connect to the last used TFS.

How can this be disabled?

Comment: Could somebody add the visual studio tag to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set **AutoLoadServer** registry key to 0.

Navigate to Team Foundation key

*HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation*

Add a registry key **AutoLoadServer** of type **REG_DWORD**

[image]

Set the value to 0 so that VS doesn't connect to TFS automatically on startup

[image]

Or create a *.reg file with the following:

**Visual Studio 2010**

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation]
> "AutoLoadServer"=dword:00000000

---

**Visual Studio 2013**

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation]
> "AutoLoadServer"=dword:00000000

---

**Visual Studio 2015**

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation]
> "AutoLoadServer"=dword:00000000

Comment: This worked for me on Visual Studio 2013 (12.0.31101.00 Update 4). Thanks! :)  Note - The Registry key in this answer is targeted specifically at Visual Studio 2010 since it calls for version 10.0 ("...VisualStudio\10.0\...") in the key.  This Registry key works for Visual Studio 2013: *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation*

Comment: @NeptuneSystems I've updated the answer to include the Visual Studio 2013 registry changed needed.