# Prevent TFS from starting at computer startup

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I installed TFSE on my computer. Now I want to stop it from auto running from when I boot the computer, but I rather not *uninstall* it. I've checked the startup list in Task Manager but it's not there. Is there any way of stopping it from auto-starting?

Comment: You shouldn't install TFS on your desktop PC. It's an enterprise piece of software that should run on a dedicated server.

Comment: Which part of TFS is autostart? Did you mean the service or the website?And why did you need this? If you just want the service and process of TFS not running automaticcy, you can stop the serveice and kill the process. If you want to prevent Visual Studio from connecting to Team Foundation Server on startup. Please refer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816331/prevent-visual-studio-from-connecting-to-team-foundation-server-on-startup

Answer (score 1):

First, just as *Daniel* says:It's not recommend to hold TFS server on your own desktop PC. If you really want it, you can install it in your Virtual machine. [Install Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631899(v=vs.120).aspx)

If you just need the service and process of TFS not running. You can stop the service manually follow **[Stop and start services, application pools, and websites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668752(v=vs.120).aspx)**

If you want to prevent Visual Studio from connecting to Team Foundation Server on startup. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816331/prevent-visual-studio-from-connecting-to-team-foundation-server-on-startup) smilar question.